# How to reference SveltKit $lib from oustide sveltekit (from commandline tsx)

Tags: sveltekit, tsx

I have a sveltekit project with the schema:

```
util
src
  lib
  routes
static
```

In **src/lib** I have utility ts functions which reference $lib from anywhere in my code. They work fine while working inside sveltekit.

I have other utility typescript functions in the **util** folder, which I run directly using tsx from the commandline.

My question is how can I reference $lib from these utility functions? I could just reference it using '../src/lib/etc...' from my function; the problem is that if the called function also references $lib, tsx is not able to decode it. I would need to explicitly change all $lib references in my code.

the **tsconfig.json** file that sveltekit generates is there at the root. It references the $lib definitions (which it does but only work while running sveltekit). I tried to explicitly pointing the tsx to the tsconfig file `tsx --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json`  but doesn't make a difference.

Any suggestions?